# Extracting values from XML formatted output

Tags: xml, elementtree

I'm trying to get just the ip address values from the output shown below:

```
<sc-list>
    <sc address="10.13.11.103"/>
    <sc address="10.13.11.107"/>
</sc-list>
```

I tried using etree, but i can't seem to get to the ip values (see code below)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filepath = "C:\Development\pq-python-examples\ip_numbers.xml"
tree = ET.parse(filepath)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print (child.tag, child.attrib)
```

The output i get looks like this:

('sc', {'address': '10.13.11.103'})

('sc', {'address': '10.13.11.107'})

Can someone help me to get just the ip adresses?

10.13.11.103

10.13.11.107

Thanks.

Comment: Do `print (child.attrib.get('address'))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to add appropriate language tag (`python`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.attrib` property returns a dictionary of attributes, which means you can use `child.attrib.get('address')` to get the IP address.

This is a safe way of getting the address because your program won't crash if a child does not have an `address`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, your my hero!